# How can I list installed network cards using Terminal?

Tags: command-line, networking

How to list **all network cards installed** in my Ubuntu using a single terminal command?

Answer (score 47):

while  the above works, there are other options with less typing.

```
ip link show
```

or my favorite, netstat

```
netstat -i
```

you can also  use ifconfig and iwconfig for additional information or information about a specific device

```
ifconfig eth0

iwconfig wlp1s0
```

sort  of depends on the sort of information you wish to display.

Comment: Typing only `ip link` yields the same result as with `show`.

Answer (score 16):

You can use:

```
lspci
```

`lspci` : will list all PCI devices

Now try this command:

```
lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'
```

The command will list network cards available and installed and highlight `Ethernet` if found .

[image: example output]

Answer (score 4):

If the cards are installed physically but not configured you can see them like this:

```
cat /proc/net/dev
```

Answer (score 3):

The following command provides detailed information about the hardware:

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

This command will show you the current NetworkManager configuration:

```
nmcli
```