# Lenovo 130 15ast - 18.04 - RTL8821ce

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo

I'm very new to Linux and this community.  The computer is a gift to a friend who will only use Ubuntu and needs wifi.

I bought the Lenovo. Installed an SSD. Downloaded 18.02 and installed.

There is no wireless showing on the main screen.  Ethernet is okay.

I found two articles here which had text to paste into Terminal. These ran apparently without error.  Both predicted that wireless would appear after a reboot but it doesn't for me.

I notice that airplane mode can't be found in Activities.  Working F5 (airplane symbol) does nothing.

I tried other text (lsm?) in Terminal which supposedly looks for installed drivers.  In the long list is a Realtek network block of info.  It has some text saying "unclaimed."

I read that I must be sure that secure boot in BIOS must be disabled.  I don't find that in the BIOS but I've set things to l egacy boot before running terminal input above.

Much of the discussion I read here is beyond me.

Here is what I ran and results:

---

From: [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce)

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

The result was:

```
diane@diane-Lenovo-ideapad-130-15AST:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
[sudo] password for diane: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for diane: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 475 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5,069 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 132203 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../build-essential_12.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.4ubuntu1) over (12.4ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9.2) over (2.3-3ubuntu9.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4) over (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic_4.15.0-29.31_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31) over (4.15.0-29.31) ...
Setting up build-essential (12.4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9.2) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up git (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4) ...
diane@diane-Lenovo-ideapad-130-15AST:~$
```

I rebooted and found no sign of a wireless device

---

From: [How can I make my Realtek RTL8821CE wireless hardware work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098595/how-can-i-make-my-realtek-rtl8821ce-wireless-hardware-work)

I ran:

```
cd /tmp/
sudo apt install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

The result was:

```
diane@diane-Lenovo-ideapad-130-15AST:~$ cd /tmp/
diane@diane-Lenovo-ideapad-130-15AST:/tmp$ sudo apt install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
[sudo] password for diane: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for diane: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 395 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5,069 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 132301 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../build-essential_12.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.4ubuntu1) over (12.4ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9.2) over (2.3-3ubuntu9.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4) over (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic_4.15.0-29.31_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31) over (4.15.0-29.31) ...
Setting up build-essential (12.4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9.2) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up git (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4) ...
diane@diane-Lenovo-ideapad-130-15AST:/tmp$
```

I rebooted and found no indication of a wireless device.

---

From: [How can I list installed network cards using Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425859/how-can-i-list-installed-network-cards-using-terminal)

I ran:

```
lspci
```

And got:

```
diane@diane-Lenovo-ideapad-130-15AST:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1576
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1577
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 98e4 (rev ea)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15b3
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1578
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157d
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157a
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 4b)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4b)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b5
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

I rebooted and there was no sign of a wireless device

---

from another source, I entered

```
lshw -c network (but first typed sudo -i)
```

and got:

```
root@diane-Lenovo-ideapad-130-15AST:~# lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: 9c:5a:44:06:ed:f1
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.113 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:30 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0400000-f0400fff memory:f0100000-f0103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1000000-f100ffff
```

---

Comment: You might want to check your text - Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format (with exception being speciality releases like Ubuntu Core 18), and there was no 2018-February release? or was the 18.02 a version for something else? in which case please clarify  Also providing the links to what you followed, or at least the commands you tried & results would be useful instead of vague "*found articles .. pasted into terminal..*" - what articles? what commands & what output did you get (eg. what was around the '*unclaimed*' ...)?

Comment: Good news, support for the rtl8221ce has been posted to the mainline kernel, not sure when it will eventually appear for us, but tomaspinho [comments below](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce/issues/142#issuecomment-633739625), [the reference](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce/issues/142#issue-621954604).

Answer (score 1):

Hi mine too had the same problem this worked for me.
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"

Answer (score 1):

I had to install a [driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported), following the steps here to find guides for multiple different chip sets.

In the here discussed case [RTL8821CE](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/wlan-modul-nicht-aktieviert-unter-ubuntu-18-04/#post-8985121):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Secure Boot has nothing to do with it. We would, however require some extra information from you to help you.

Please update the post with more information (output of lsusb , dmesg , uname -a) and we might be able to help only then.

Otherwise, the ppa at [rtl8821ce](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) has what you want. Follow the steps there. Ask questions here if you get stuck.

Please follow the instructions on that site for Lenovo Laptops:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
```

To permanently blacklist:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

Comment: I have the same issue and tried to follow your steps, but it did not seem to work, leaving me with No Wi-Fi Adapter found.

Comment: @mrk Are you sure you had the same issue? Can you provide the output of lshw -c network and dmesg (preferably on pastebin).

Comment: So I am not quite sure whether I had the same problem - installing the driver did it for me. I added more detail in an answer bellow. Thanks for the response.